# Creation of a new data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, markdown, knitr

The thing is that I have to create a new data frame with the observations in which "George Clegane" (from an already existing data frame called "got") is the attacking commander. I create a new chunk, I write the code in it and it executes perfectly. The problem appears when I want to knit the RMarkdown that I'm working on, because R tells me that there's an error but I don't really get it. I mean, I already executed it without any problem and created the new data frame out of it so, what's wrong??

This is my code:

```
 got %>%
   filter(attacker_commander == "Gregor Clegane")
```

This is what R tells me: Could not find function "%>%"

Thanks!

I haven't really tried anything since I don't get where the problem comes from.

Comment: I'm no expert with dataframe, but the error message clearly states that it does not understand what you're trying to do.  Where did you get the %>% bit from? That's where your code is getting confused.  Maybe go back to the source of where that came from and provide that as a starting point?

Comment: Do you have `library(dplyr)` or `library(tidyverse)` in your R markdown document?